# Properties in asp:GridView and asp:TemplateField

Tags: html, vb.net, webforms

Is there a property in `asp:GridView`>`asp:TemplateField` that will allow you to limit the number of entries posted when pulling data from a database?

Comment: Please include the database you are using in the tag list.

Comment: What exactly do you need of the database?

Comment: If you want to limit the number of rows returned to the grid, the  database is probably the best place to o it. I would provide an example but the syntax differs from DB to DB.

Comment: Oh I never thought of that. Its a SQL Server database.

Answer (score 0):

Using SQL Server, you can limit the number of rows returned by using TOP n-rows, ex.

```
SELECT Top 10 Column1, Column2, ColumnN FROM YourTable WHERE YourConditions
```